# Resque-Status gem not giving status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am also using resque-status gem in my project to get the bacground process status, but the problem is its not giving me the status :( its always saying status.status = queued 
I'm trying to get the job id from my controller by:
`job_id = PatstatResqueWorker.create('query' => @query, 'database' => "localhost")`
this thing works.

but, if i try to get the status by:
`status = Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.get(job_id)`
it gives alwasy "queued" :(

Here is my Resque Worker Class:

```
require 'resque'
require 'resque/job_with_status'

class PatstatResqueWorker < Resque::JobWithStatus
  @queue = :patstat_worker_q

  def self.perform(jobid, options)
    results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(options['query'])
  end
end
```

could anybody please tell me whats the wrong?

Comment: Hey A.Biswas - did you ever find a solution. I am running into the same problem and banging my head against the wall.